# How to bind TextBox to datasource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, c#-3.0

I want to bind a textbox to a data source so that I can implement IDataErrorInfo.

How would I achieve the functionality that essentially does what

```
TextBoxClientRenewalDate.DataSource = contract.RenewalDate;
```

would do, if it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're looking for, but usually you would just assign the value to the `Text` property, like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = MyDataTable.Rows[0].Field<string>("SomeColumn");
```

I suppose you could use the `DataBinder` object too:

```
//not positive here, but it should be close
TextBox1.Text = (string)DataBinder.Eval(MyDataTable, "SomeColumn");
```